# Contains method on java exception

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to see if the thrown exception contains a particular word, like in the code below, but my IDE says the 'contains()' method is undefined for the type Exception. How would I do that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  try {
     // blah blah
  } catch (Exception z) {
     if (z.contains("UnknownHostException")) {
       System.out.print("Unknown Host");
     }
     // blah blah
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think class `Exception` even has a `contains` method? Where did you get that idea? Did you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of class [`Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)?

Comment: Why not try to catch `UnknownHostException`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are trying to inspect the exception *message*:

```
z.getMessage().contains("UnknownHostException")
```

But in general you directly specify the *type* of the exception you want to catch. Something like this:

```
try {
    // some code
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    System.out.print("Unknown Host");
} catch (Exception other) {
    // other exceptions go here
}
```

See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html), especially [The catch Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
z.getMessage().contains(...)
```

But don't do that if you're simply checking the type of the exception: catch `UnknownHostException` directly:

```
} catch (UnknownHostException z) {
```

In order that you don't get confused by an exception with the message e.g.:

```
I am not an UnknownHostException.
```

You should only rarely catch `Exception` (only if a method you're calling *throws* `Exception`; and then, methods should rarely throw `Exception`, unless they are framework methods).